# approximate polynomial by linear inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, interpolation, polynomial-math, approximation

I have a polynomial

```
b*p + a*q + y = 0
```

where b,p,a,q,y are integer variables. It specifies some area.

1) If there a way (an algorithm) to specify linear inequalities, that the area they are describe, will include an area of polynomial?

2) If there a way (an algorithm) to specify a set of linear inequalities, the the area they are describe, will be included in an area of polynomial?

This question also applies, in general, to any polynomial:

```
a1*x1^y11*...*xm^ym1 + ak*x1^y1k*...*xm^ymk = 0
```

where
x1,...,xm - integer variables, a1,...ak, y11, ..., ymk - integers.